# width in <table> is not the same as that in <p> HTML

Tags: html, css

```
.Text {
 width:500px;
font-size: 18px;
 font-family: Arial;
  color: #0000FF;
background-color: #F0E0F0;
 line-height: 1.16667;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #FF8000;
 margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 8px;
}
```

Here, the `<p>` and `<table>` use the same class `"Text"`;

```
<p class="Text">
<table class='Text'>
 <tr style='vertical-align: baseline;'>
  <td style='text-align: left;'>something</td>
  <td style='text-align: left;'>something</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</p>
```

However, the final effect in explorer shows that, `<table>` is narrower than `<p>`

Why they are not the same, I give the `"Text"` class a fixed width!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`padding` is not included in the width for the `content-box` `box-sizing` model.  Use `border-box`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8vVGT/

It's also worth pointing out that `<table>` is not a valid descendant of `<p>`